# Different delivery prices for different currencies

Tags: magento2, magento-1, configuration, currency, multicurrency

I have two currencies. The base currency is GBP, the other one is EUR. The client wants fixed shipping rates - 5 for GBP and 6 for EUR. I've set the one for the base currency but how can I set the rate for EUR to be 6 EUR instead of 5*(current_gbp_to_eur_conversion_rate)?

Answer (score 2):

This is not configurable unless you use separate websites per base currency.